# Set builder form for representing strings

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation, formal-languages

Is there a way to represent strings or palindromes using set notation?

For representing palindrome using set notation, I arrived at this notation  $$S=\{ab^{n}c:N\; |\; n \geq 1 \land n \leq 3\}$$

I want to represent a set of palindromes with length 3.Please help me out with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A word $w$ has length $3$ if and only if $w=abc$ for some symbols $a,b,c$.  To be a palindrome, we must also have $a=c$.  We can summarize this by saying that for $w$ to be a palindrome of length 3, it must have the form $w=aba$.  The set of such palindromes over some alphabet $\Sigma$ is therefore

$$\{w \mid \exists a,b \in \Sigma. w = aba \}$$

which we usually abbreviate to $$\{aba \mid a,b\in \Sigma\}.$$

Your suggestion, $\{ab^nc \mid n\ge 1\land n\le 3\}$, does not seem to represent the set of palindromes of length 3, for several reasons: if $n=3$, then $ab^nc$ has length $5$, not length $3$; if $a\ne c$ then $abc$ is not a palindrome; etc.

Comment: Fine got it. I probably forgot to replace c with a in the set i think. But, if i substitute a integer value for n then my set will become say for n=2 $$ab^{2}a$$ which will be $$abba$$. IS it right?

Comment: Yes, but $abba$ does not have length 3.

Comment: Oh ok fine. finally understood where i went wrong in my set notation.. Thanks for helping me out.